# Can google read the window location from an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, browser, adsense

Yesterday I put a google banner in my domain, this banner was wrapped by an iframe. Some time later, I received a notification from google in which they advised me to block this secondary domain. Now I'm wondering how it is possible that google can read the top window location if the banner is in an iframe?

Comment: Anyone can do, just use `alert(document.referrer);` within the page beeing displayed as an iframe. The containing page will be set as referrer.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to say that the referrer is nulled by a proxy